# Can't switch theme after activation

Tags: plugin-development, options, switch-theme

I'm creating a plugin (I'm very newbie in this) to load custom taxonomies, custom post types and an automatic activation of a theme, so I have this code:

```
// Custom Post Types and Taxonomies
require_once('inc/cpt-taxonomies.php');

// Switch Theme
function updateTheme($theme){
    update_option('template', $theme);
    update_option('stylesheet', $theme);
    update_option('current_theme', $theme);
}
updateTheme('Creative_Grid');

require_once('inc/initial-setup-theme.php');
```

The issue is that when is activated I can't swith to other theme in Appereance Page, it's like the plugin reactivate it when a try to switch to other theme. I can confirm that when I switched to another theme all the code of the plugin run again, and I dont want that, I want to execute dthe code when is activated.

Some idea?
Other question, what kind of php conditional should I have to prevent a failure if that theme is not available?

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: When you run the code, on which hook? Maybe you have no hook, is it a plugin then runs always to a default loading and run always and set the theme values inside the settings.

Comment: Hi, I use to utilize some code in functions.php, and this is my first time with plugins. I realize myself I dont have some basic understanding on how plugins works. Yes, I was not using hooks. Below @cybmeta pointed out this question. And I realize how to solve this particular question, but this plugin has other functionalities and as said, custom post types have to use a different hook. I have other pieces of code I want to run in this plugin (it's a plugin for setting up theme functionalities), and I'm trying to find out how to make work all together... I accept recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are executing `updateTheme()` in every page load. To execute tasks only on activation you should hooke the `updateTheme()` function to the [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) action hook:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activation_callback' );
function activation_callback() {
     //The code inside this function is executed only on plugin activation
     $theme = 'twentyeleven'; //SET the value of $theme to whatever you want (not provided in the question)
     updateTheme($theme);
}

// Switch Theme
function updateTheme($theme){
    update_option('template', $theme);
    update_option('stylesheet', $theme);
    update_option('current_theme', $theme);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping. I dind't know that by default a plugin is executed every time page is loaded, and I dont know about make it work on actvation also. I need run more code only on activation, I suppouse the way to do it is execute the functions in side activation_callback(), no?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct way.

Comment: ok..., I tried but not working now. The CPTypes are not being registered, could you check out my code here adn tell me what Im doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=8fpHs7bx

Comment: register custom post types should be done on [init action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init). See [`register_post_type` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) where it says: "It will not work if called before 'init', and aspects of the newly created or modified post type will work incorrectly if called later. "

Comment: so, for understanding... if it's loaded by 'init' the cpt are not registered every time I load the page. Sorry (for my ignorance) for the question I thought everything run everytime a page is loaded by default.

Comment: The `init` action hook is triggered every time WordPress is initialized, so it is triggered on every page load. `register_post_type` must be executed at this point; not before and not after. `register_post_type` is not a task intended to be peformed only once, for example on plugin activation, it has to be done on every page load at `init` event. This a different thing of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes now I'm using that hook you told me but now I'm having other problems (I need generate some content in the way) I think they are related with hooks. I opened another question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172888/plugin-development-hooks-generate-content